# Dynamically change axml by adding textview and edittext in specific location when tick box event is triggered

Tags: c#, android, user-interface, xamarin

[image: Screenshot of UI]

I've just started work on my first android app and i'm struggling a bit with a ui issue.

When the tickbox event is triggered i want to add a new textview and edittext just above the generate menu button but below the include fruits, but i cannot find out how to achieve this. The idea is that the user has to enter a number for how many fruits they would like.

My question is how do i add a textview and edit text above the generate button using the event in c#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android        ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation  ="vertical"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">>
    <Button
        android:text="View meals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnViewMeals" />
        <Button
        android:text="View fruit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnViewFruit" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width       ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height      ="wrap_content"
            android:text               ="Meals available:"
            android:layout_marginRight ="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop   ="14.6dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width       ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height      ="wrap_content"
            android:text               ="placeholder"
            android:layout_marginRight ="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop   ="14.6dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width       ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height      ="wrap_content"
            android:text               ="Meals left:"
            android:layout_marginRight ="10dp" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width       ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height      ="wrap_content"
            android:text               ="placeholder"
            android:layout_marginRight ="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width ="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop = "0.0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width       ="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height      ="wrap_content"
            android:text               ="Meals wanted:"
            android:layout_marginRight ="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6.6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop   ="5dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id            ="@+id/inputMealsWanted"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width  ="50dp"
            android:layout_height ="37.5dp"
            android:inputType = "number"
            android:textSize = "12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <CheckBox
        android:text="Include fruits"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/cbIncludeFruit" />
        <Button
        android:text="Generate menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnViewMeals" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is question here and what is problem you faced?

Comment: Sorry i just edited the post to state my question clearly.

Comment: My recommendation will be, create the textview and edit text  in your XML and keep it invisible and make it Visible when check box is selected

Comment: As i read your xml you have kept everything static in LinearLayout and is not a good idea as for different devices it will be different so better to use Constraint Layout @Stuart

Comment: I believe  you got a answer just check my solution also it's same but the your layout seem's to be messy for different devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the textview and edittext in the xml above Generate Menu button and below include fruits checkbox.

Then in the Java file of the activity you have to add these lines in your onCreate method just after your findViewById statements.

```
textViewID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
editTextID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then you have to create an setOnCheckedChangeListener method for the check box like this below

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener
```

You have to then check for change in state for the checkbox and then use the Boolean variable from the setOnCheckedChangeListener method and where the condition is true follow the below step.

In the else condition you have to make them GONE as above.

Then in the setOnCheckedChangeListener method you have to make these items visible

```
textViewID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
editTextID.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much this was exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewMeals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View meals"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnViewFruit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewFruit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View fruit"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnViewMeals"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnViewFruit"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meals available:"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placehonder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:text="placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mealtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meals left:"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="placeholder"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mealtext"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cbIncludeFruit"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Meals wanted:"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/inputMealsWanted"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputMealsWanted"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="37.5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbIncludeFruit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Include fruits"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/custom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnViewmenu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cbIncludeFruit"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/customText"
            android:text="CustomTest"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/customEditTest"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/customEditTest"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/customText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewmenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/custom"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try above Layout for better result and just make the whole custom Layout GONE or VISIBLE based on your click event

```
cbIncludeFruit.setOnClickListener {
        if(cbIncludeFruit.isChecked()) {
            custom.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE) 
        }else{
            custom.setvisibility(View.GONE) 
        }
    }
```

> Add above in the onStart of your Activity

Sorry for delay in answer but i was writing and testing constraint layout and work's perfectly.